# My url is redirected to other link

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-web-services, url, redirect, nginx

My domain is 
www.xyz.com/audit2017
but when I enter www.xyz.com/audit it redirects me to audit2017, 
I don't remember it is done by my previous developer so right now I am unable to contact him, 
I need a expert help in this. 
I am using AWS server and manage it with the help of putty.
My website is developed in CodeIgniter.
I have changed the name of the folder to 2018 but it is redirecting me to audit2017.

Comment: First of all check the file ../application/config/config.php and check for `$config['base_url']` and check the routes on the same directory but `routes.php` and then every single link on every view if some of the link are not called via  `$routes`.

Answer (score 0):

go to application->config->config.php search `$config['base_url']` and then paste there this code

```
$base  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $base;
```

hope this works for you

Comment: $config['base_url'] = '';

$ark_root  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ark_root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $ark_root;

Comment: Have a look at my config.php file

Comment: no just past my code there will do the rest...no need any more configurations or changes..just paste it and will work..or like this 
$ark_root  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ark_root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $ark_root;

Comment: remove first ($config['base_url'] =) part hope this will work for you

Comment: remove this from beginning $config['base_url'] =